# How to generate an array only containing 0.0 and 1.0 in python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create an array only containing 0.0 and 1.0 with a size [20,3].

I tried using the function: `np.random.randint(0,2,[20,3])`, but it only returned 0 and 1 instead of 0.0 and 1.0.

I am new to python code, if the question is not clear, I am open to made some edits to it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So convert it.  `np.random.randint(0,2,[20,3]).astype(np.float64)`

Comment: You could use `np.random.choice([0.0,1.0], [20,3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways for it.

In addition to use `.astype(np.float64)`, another opiton is that you can generate the values as follows (generating rand values and round it to convert into 0 or 1 using `np.round_()`)

```py
import numpy as np

result = np.random.rand(20, 3)
result = np.round_(result)
print(result)
```

```
# result
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @czy Was it helpful?